# GoDaddy include_path and auto_prepend_file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, include-path

I'm working in a GoDaddy shared hosting environment (Linux, PHP 7.1). I want to automatically prepend a file, globally, but I can't seem to get it working with an .htaccess or php.ini file.

I've tried variations on the following to no avail:

### php.ini

```
include_path = ".:/home/username/public_html"
auto_prepend_file = "./includes/autoload.php"
```

### .htaccess

```
php_value include_path ".:/home/username/public_html"
php_value auto_prepend_file "./includes/autoload.php"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've personally experienced major issues with Godaddy in the past, and if you do a little searching around the internet, you'll find that they've got a bad reputation. So, my first recommendation would be to change hosts. It's easy, and Godaddy gave me a refund for my unused hosting when I canclled. Next, you might think about using a framework or otherwise route all of your requests through index.php. If you do that you could accomplish what your're trying to do with a simple include at the top of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using a [.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) file:

> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a
>   per-directory basis.

I also found [this documentation](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-need-to-use-8913) from GoDaddy useful.